# How to fill NA with minimum value of rows for selected column per user with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
    sample = {'user_id': ['u_id1', 'u_id2', 'u_id3','u_ud4'],
    'len_1': [150, 'NA', 50, 50],
     'len_2': [150, 200, 50, 60],
     'len_3': [200, 210, 90, 50],
      'len_4': [200, 205, 90, 40],

     'speed_1': [140, 'NA', 'NA','NA'],
     'speed_2': [140, 215, 90, 'NA'],
     'speed_3': ['NA', 210, 95, 50],
      'speed_4': ['NA', 215, 95, 30],

     'value_1': ['NA', 215, 'NA', 'NA'],
     'value_2': [130, 'NA', 95, 50],
      'value_3': [120, 'NA', 'NA', 40],
     'value_4': ['NA', 'NA', 90, 10]}
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sample)
    df.set_index('user_id')
    df
```

I have the above data frame sample. It has 'NA' values for some of the columns.
[image]
I want to fill 'NA' Values. 
Example:-

'u_id1' has "NA' at 'speed_3' and 'speed_4', so 'speed_3 = 'speed_4 = min `{speed_1, speed_2,speed_3, speed_4}` => 140

'u_id2' has "NA' at 'len_1' so 'len_1 = min `{len_1, len_2, len_3, len_4}` => 200.

If possible I want to check the percentage of 'NA' values. i.e per `{len_1, len_2, len_3, len_4}`, per  `{speed_1, speed_2,speed_3, speed_4}` etc. for every user. So that I can decide whether to fill with min value or not. e.g if 75% of {value_1, value_2,value_3, value_4} are 'NA' then do not fill with NA values (Because letter I want to filter these out).

The expected output should look something similar

```
   sample = {'user_id': ['u_id1', 'u_id2', 'u_id3','u_ud4'],
    'len_1': [150, 200, 50, 50],
     'len_2': [150, 200, 50, 50],
     'len_3': [200, 210, 90, 50],
      'len_4': [200, 205, 90, 50],

     'speed_1': [140, 215, 95, 30],
     'speed_2': [140, 215, 95, 30],
     'speed_3': [140, 215, 95, 50],
      'speed_4': [140, 215, 95, 30],

     'value_1': [120, 215, 90, 10],
     'value_2': [130, 'NA', 95, 50],
      'value_3': [120, 'NA', 90, 40],
     'value_4': [120, 'NA', 90, 10]}
df_out = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sample)
```

[image]
 Note: for user 'u_id2' `{ value_2,value_3, value_4}` remain NA since 75% of them were 'NA' values

I appreciate any help on how to approach this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need replace missing values per groups by columns names splitted by `_` use:

```
sample = {'user_id': ['u_id1', 'u_id2', 'u_id3','u_ud4'],
            'len_1': [150, 'NA', 50, 50],
             'len_2': [150, 200, 50, 50],
             'len_3': [200, 210, 90, 50],
             'len_4': [200, 210, 90, 50],    
             'speed_1': [140, 'NA', 'NA','NA'],
             'speed_2': [140, 215, 95, 'NA'],
             'speed_3': ['NA', 215, 95, 50],
             'speed_4': ['NA', 215, 95, 50],
             'value_1': ['NA', 215, 'NA', 'NA'],
             'value_2': [140, 'NA', 95, 50],
             'value_3': ['NA', 'NA', 'NA', 50],
             'value_4': ['NA', 'NA', 'NA', 50]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sample)
```

---

```
#convert to index and convert NA to np.nan
df = df.set_index('user_id')
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

print (df)
         len_1  len_2  len_3  len_4  speed_1  speed_2  speed_3  speed_4  \
user_id                                                                   
u_id1    150.0    150    200    200    140.0    140.0      NaN      NaN   
u_id2      NaN    200    210    210      NaN    215.0    215.0    215.0   
u_id3     50.0     50     90     90      NaN     95.0     95.0     95.0   
u_ud4     50.0     50     50     50      NaN      NaN     50.0     50.0   

         value_1  value_2  value_3  value_4  
user_id                                      
u_id1        NaN    140.0      NaN      NaN  
u_id2      215.0      NaN      NaN      NaN  
u_id3        NaN     95.0      NaN      NaN  
u_ud4        NaN     50.0     50.0     50.0
```

You can use [`DataFrame.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) for check missing values, then [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with first values of splitted columns names and get `mean` with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for return `DataFrame` filled by same values per groups, compare by thresh:

```
mask = df.isna().groupby(lambda x: x.split('_')[0], axis=1).transform('mean') < .75
print (mask)
         len_1  len_2  len_3  len_4  speed_1  speed_2  speed_3  speed_4  \
user_id                                                                   
u_id1     True   True   True   True     True     True     True     True   
u_id2     True   True   True   True     True     True     True     True   
u_id3     True   True   True   True     True     True     True     True   
u_ud4     True   True   True   True     True     True     True     True   

         value_1  value_2  value_3  value_4  
user_id                                      
u_id1      False    False    False    False  
u_id2      False    False    False    False  
u_id3      False    False    False    False  
u_ud4       True     True     True     True
```

Then replace by [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) only values filtered by mask:

```
df[mask] = df.fillna(df.groupby(lambda x: x.split('_')[0], axis=1).transform('min'))
print (df)
         len_1  len_2  len_3  len_4  speed_1  speed_2  speed_3  speed_4  \
user_id                                                                   
u_id1    150.0    150    200    200    140.0    140.0    140.0    140.0   
u_id2    200.0    200    210    210    215.0    215.0    215.0    215.0   
u_id3     50.0     50     90     90     95.0     95.0     95.0     95.0   
u_ud4     50.0     50     50     50     50.0     50.0     50.0     50.0   

         value_1  value_2  value_3  value_4  
user_id                                      
u_id1        NaN    140.0      NaN      NaN  
u_id2      215.0      NaN      NaN      NaN  
u_id3        NaN     95.0      NaN      NaN  
u_ud4       50.0     50.0     50.0     50.0
```

Comment: Yours coerce works only for the first user and speed_i value.  I want to do it for every user in a row per each variable group (i.e speed_1, speed_2, speed_3, speed_4) , (len_1,  len_2 , len_3  len_4),  and ( value_1,  value_2,  value_3,  value_4). Sorry, maybe my question is not clear. I made some update above

Comment: @ewalel - Can you create expected output DataFrame? What `NaN`s are replace and what not?

Comment: I updated, the question with expected input and output

Comment: @ewalel - Can you add to your question output of may solution? Because for me it working nice.

Comment: @ jezrael, Perfect! it works for filling the min value per variable group for each user, but not for the  case of u_id2 for the variable group {value_1, value_2, value_3, value_4}. That is do not fill if the percentage of 'NA' values is >=75%. i.e per {len_1, len_2, len_3, len_4}, per  {speed_1, speed_2,speed_3, speed_4} etc.

Comment: @ jezrael, It returns the same result. In order not to fill the NA if the number of variables per variable group with  'NA' values is >=75%, we need to count # of variable groups with 'NA' and check how many are they(in percentage). But it confuses me on how to do it :) . For u_id2, 1/3 of {value_1, value_2, value_3, value_4} are 'NA', so don't fill them with NA. I appreciate your help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193448/discussion-between-jezrael-and-ewalel).